# run specific schema:update | doctrine doesn't recognize table chages symfony2

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I use Symfony 2.4 and PostgreSQL. I manually (raw SQL) added new column to my table. On localhost everything's fine, but on server there's a problem. When I run `app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` it tells that it should add column (which I've already added manually) and execute some other SQL queries (which I don't want to run).

The question is - is there way to run only one specific query from that list `The Schema-Tool would execute "6" queries to update the database.` or to "let know" Doctrine that I already added new column, because for now it throws error (Symfony doesn't see my new column on server).

my column in model

```
/**
 * @var boolean $isEmailConfirmed
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="isemailconfirmed", type="boolean", options={"default":FALSE})
 */
private $isEmailConfirmed;
```

my raw SQL query was:

```
alter table player add column isEmailConfirmed boolean default false not null;
```

I tried to clear cache and clear Doctrine cache, but it doesn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you've manually added `isEmailConfirmed` column which is not the same as `isemailconfirmed` (case sensitivity), which is defined in `name="isemailconfirmed"` in annotation. That's why Doctrine wants to add this column once again.

The second thing is that you probably should execute also the other of these 6 queries, because other way it may lead to issues in your app as the real schema will be different that Doctrine expects it to be.

And to answer your questions:

No there's no way to tell Doctrine to execute only one of suggested queries or "tell it that you've already added this column", because it compares the expected schema and the actual one at runtime every time the command is being executed. Anyway it's not recommended to use `doctrine:schema:update` on production. Some DB migration tool is recommended to use. E.g. there's Doctrine Migrations tool for this job.

Comment: thanks for reply, i changed the name, but it didn't help. doctrine still tells me that it should run this query. and for the second on, the project is on production, I don't know why previous developers left it in this way, but for now i cannot run them

Comment: Make sure that the column definition is **exactly** the same as expected. Also you could provide the query that Doctrine is suggesting to compare with your raw SQL that you've executed.

Comment: Anyway you should not do it this way. You should rely on Doctrine's tools.